# Clicking visible close button inside a dialog

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Have a potential problem at hand. I have an overlay form that comes just after successful registration. I have tried by X path too but that does not help(as in recognize it).

Now i am trying to have a class recognize ( the complete overlay form) and then click the 'X' link on the form. However the problem is the compound class.

This is the complete class that recognize the overlay form:

```
ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all registerModel-main-dialog ui-draggable signup_thanks
```

This is the class for the 'X' link:

```
ui-icon ui-icon-closethick
```

The website is http://www.saksoff5th.com/

Comment: If you're hoping to get an answer, then you should publish the relevant Python code and the relevant piece of HTML from the web-page that you are trying to control.

Comment: What is happening when you try to interact with the elements?  Is an exception being thrown?

Comment: Please see the code. Site i am using is saksoff5th.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your site is http://saksoff5th.com, I can provide working code for you.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.saksoff5th.com/")

driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds

driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".sign-in > span").click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".ui-dialog[style*='display: block'] .ui-icon-closethick").click()

# If you prefer explicit wait, you can do these
# WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".sign-in > span")).click()
# WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".ui-dialog[style*='display: block'] .ui-icon-closethick")).click()
```

Since you haven't provided your code, I guess two possible issues with your code:

- You didn't use WebDriverWait, which is needed before clicking, since your elements are not available immediately.
- There are two other dialogs with same class names, you need to find the visible one.

If you are happy with the answer, please accept like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/220697). Otherwise provide feedbacks below.

Comment: This is the error i am getting :- File "C:\Python27\lib\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 164, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
NoSuchElementException: Message: u'Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".ui-dialog[style*=\'display: block\'] .ui-icon-closethick"}' ; Stacktrace:

Comment: This is the code that i am using.from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.saksoff5th.com')
browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('WELCOME').click()
browser.switch_to_frame('loginModel')
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='dwfrm_login_username']").send_keys('test80@rediffmail.com')

Comment: elem1 = browser.find_element_by_class_name('selectLogin')
a = elem1.find_element_by_id('login1').click()
browser.find_element_by_id('dwfrm_login_register').click()

browser.switch_to_frame('registerModel')
browser.implicitly_wait(10)
browser.find_element_by_id('dwfrm_profile_customer_firstname').send_keys('Hello')
browser.find_element_by_id('dwfrm_profile_customer_lastname').send_keys('Sharma')
browser.find_element_by_id('dwfrm_profile_customer_zippostalcode').send_keys('07302')

Comment: browser.find_element_by_id('dwfrm_profile_customer_emailconfirm').send_keys('test80@rediffmail.com')
browser.find_element_by_id('dwfrm_profile_login_password').send_keys('Password0')
browser.find_element_by_id('dwfrm_profile_login_passwordconfirm').send_keys('Password0')
browser.find_element_by_name('dwfrm_profile_confirm').click()
browser.implicitly_wait(15)
print('a')

browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".ui-dialog[style*='display: block'] .ui-icon-closethick").click()

Comment: @user3337644: Because you need switch out the frame before click close button. `browser.switch_to_default_content()`. You should really post everything (your site, your code, exceptions, your step etc.) in your original question from the beginning to avoid waste your own time.